# How to use SSMS to connect to a SQL db without firewall rule?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm aware of the [Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#creating-and-managing-firewall-rules). And have created both server-level and database-level firewall rules for accessing an Azure SQL db.

I'm now at a coffee shop using SQL Server Mgmt. Studio to work on an Azure SQL db, but DO NOT want to accept the coffee shop's IP address as a whitelisted IP.

How can I access my Azure SQL Server without whitelisting every IP address I wish to connect from? Is there some type of Azure proxy to use?

Thank you

Comment: You can automate updating the same firewall rule by just running a PowerShell script. Let me know if you want me to share with you a sample script.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that you can not connect from an IP address that isn’t whitelisted.

AFAIK, there isn’t a proxy available for such scenario.

As a workaround,

- you can add and remove the IP from whitelist later or
- have a VM (on Azure or elsewhere) with SSMS that is able to connect to your DB and you could remote into that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the offer @AlbertoMorillo. I decided to go with:

`curl ifconfig.me` to determine IP address, then

`EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule 
@name = N'name_your_rule',
@start_ip_address = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', @end_ip_address = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'`

to create the rule, then

`EXECUTE sp_delete_database_firewall_rule N'name_your_rule';` when I'm finished.